# Use of special characters in Facebook captions

Tags: facebook, encoding, utf-8

we are having problems with uploading subtitles to a video on Facebook. The problem is the video is in Slovene language and it uses characters like "Č", "Š" and "Ž". Usually this would be 1250 Central European encoding but Facebook wants UTF-8 encoding.

We export our subtitles in UTF-8, we upload them, however we can't see any subtitles later. If we delete all special characters, subtitles show up and work normally.

We also already tried using codes like these without success.
 http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=dec

Part of the code from SRT file:

[image]

And the text:

1
00:00:04,227 --> 00:00:05,364
Živijo iz Ljubljane!

2
00:00:05,365 --> 00:00:08,153
Ali greva raziskovat
staro mestno jedro?

3
00:00:08,154 --> 00:00:08,880
Za mano.

4
00:00:15,368 --> 00:00:16,686
Na Starem trgu 11a

Any ideas?

Jan

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is what you are doing. But we have no idea what your subtitles looks like

Comment: I have provided you the code in my original question.

Comment: How would we know what encoding it is?